# how does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{1+n}$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I thought that to prove an alternating series two tests needed to be proven

$$a_n \ge a_{n+1}$$

which is true and

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n  = 0 \ \  \ \ \ \ \text{which}  \ \ \ \ \ \  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+n}=0$$

yet sources (wolfram alpha) indicate that it does not converge

Comment: Sources are wrong. What sources?

Comment: Which sources? The series does converge (not absolutely, though).

Comment: can you explicitly mention the sources? please

Comment: As the previous somments ask, please provide us explicitly the sources. What they say is totally wrong.

Comment: why an upvote for this? :P

Comment: It converges to $\ln 2$, in fact.

Comment: I put that into wolfram alpha and it says that by comparison test the series does not converge

Comment: By wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-1%29%5En+1%2F%28n%2B1%29%2C+n%3D0+to+infinity it is converges to ln2.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Alright, yea it does, the -1^n registered as -(1)^n not (-1)^n thank you mates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is convergent, moreover we can obtain that:
$$
\begin{align}
&\phantom{={}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{1+n} \\
&=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots \\
&=\ln2
\end{align}
$$
cause
$$
\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{1+n}x^n
$$
and the original series is $\ln(1+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it converges. Let $b_n=(-1)^n$ and $a_n=\frac {1}{n+1}$. Then $a_n>0$ is decreasing that goes to $0$.Also $b_n$ has bounded partial sums because $\sum_{k=0}^{n} b_n\leq 1$.So using Dirichlet's Proposition we have that it converges. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test